# Bar plot counts for given period by minute interval

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a  pandas dataframe where one column is a timestamp in seconds, for example:

```
    pid         timestamp

0   2214639     2015-11-16 00:22:29
1   23931782    2015-11-16 00:45:02
2   25318683    2015-11-16 00:31:29
...
```

What I'd like to get is the number of one minute intervals over the whole interval.

For example if I do this:

```
ts = df["timestamp"]
ts.groupby(ts.dt.minute).count().plot(kind="bar", figsize=(12, 9),
                                           title="PID's minute")
```

What I get using this are counts by minute, from 0 to 60:
[image]

What I'd like is, for example to get count in each minute from, for example, 11:30 to 13:45 but not grouped by minutes 0-60, but by each minute in whole interval, so if for example 50 events happened between 12:00 and 12:01, that is a point, from 13:00-13:01 is another point, not grouped together as in above picture. So x axis would have values between 11:30 to 13:45, y values would be counts by each minute. Also, ticks on x axis can be in 15 min intervals so it's not so crowded.

Comment: @hitzg I explained where I got stuck. How to group by some custom time interval in custom range in pandas.

Comment: I think you are looking for a histogram. there you can set a custom bin size.